# Excel UDF giving value error if selected range is not from a single sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, concatenation, textjoin

The following code is made to concatenate cells with a delimiter.
The Ref here can be a continuous range or a group of ranges put inside a bracket. The only limitation i'm
getting is that if the group of cells contain range from two different sheets the UDF gives value error.

```
Function CONCATENATEMULTIPLE(Ref As Range, Separator As String) As String
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Result As String
Dim plc2remove As Long
plc2remove = Len(Separator)


For Each Cell In Ref
If Not Cell.Value = "" Then
 Result = Result & Cell.Value & Separator
 End If
Next Cell
If Result = "" Then
CONCATENATEMULTIPLE = "NO DATA TO SHOW"
Else
CONCATENATEMULTIPLE = Left(Result, Len(Result) - plc2remove)
End If
End Function
```

I think the solution is to identify .parent property of each cell when iterating through it but I cannot make it work.

[Concatenation works when group of ranges are from single sheet like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8Gnr.png)

[But doesn't work when range from another sheet is also included like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKmKy.png)

Comment: You cannot select ranges from different worksheets at the same time. You possibly need another range argument (`Ref2`). Why don't you explain what you're trying to achieve in more detail? Surely you must know that you can do `=CONCATENATEMULTIPLE(A1:A10,",")&","&CONCATENATEMULTIPLE(Sheet2!A1:A10,",")`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 added screenshot. See now then it will make more sense what I'm asking for.
Moreover sure I know one can do like that but I don't see the benefit of UDF if you need to use it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Function myConcat(Sep As String, ParamArray Ref() As Variant) As String
    Dim s, c, m As String
    m = ""
    For Each s In Ref
        For Each c In s.Cells
            m = m & c.Value
            If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then m = m & Sep
        Next
    Next
    If Len(m) = 0 Then
        myConcat= "NO DATA TO SHOW"
    Else
        myConcat = Left(m, Len(m) - Len(Sep))
    End If
End Function
```

It can be called with something like:

```
=myConcat(", ",Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!A3,Sheet2!A1,A1:A2)
```

Note - the ranges are not gathered in brackets.

Comment: Excellent! It works as expected. By the way could you please explain why the original code only wants to accept range from a single sheet only?

Comment: Because it's being expressed as a single range. A limitation in Excel is that a single range expression can only contain ranges on the same sheet. `myConcat` accepts an array of single expressions and processes them one at a time.